# Hyundai coupe 2005, engine light blinking

Tags: hyundai-coupe

I bought this car around a year ago, it works fine on a day to day basis but if I try to go on the motorway and go over 70mph the engine light will start blinking, if I drop it back down to below 70mph it goes off and stays off, the car will then continue to run fine as long as I don't go over 70mph.
I have taken it to a garage who have plugged in a diagnostic machine but no error codes are coming up, does anyone have an idea of what it could be as I would like to get this repaired before something major happens to the engine?

Thanks

Comment: 70Mph is the motorway speed limit in the UK, which is where I assume you are. Is it possible you bought a car with a limiter on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not always the cause but often a blinking check engine light on a Hyundai is an indicator of a misfire, which itself can be caused by a failed ignition coil, bad spark plug, injector issues etc.

One thing that is worth bearing in mind is that Hyundai use a blinking light to indicate that the detected issue is considered severe and may result in damage to the engine or catalytic converter.

If you aren't experiencing any rough running but just the light then another possibility is the Mass Air Flow (MAF) sensor - if this has failed in such a way that it's producing erroneous readings that might only become visible once a certain amount of airflow has been reached (which would fit with your symptoms only occurring at high speed).

It seems very strange that no codes showed up - the two things are basically inseparable! If you can get access to an OBD-II dongle and a suitable app/device to read them I'd suggest plugging in - going up to 70 to trigger the light and then *before* you turn the engine off again try reading the codes.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your input on this issue, i think a friend of mine has one of these diagnostic machines so firstly will try what you said and plug it in then go on the motorway to see if I can get a code immediately as the light comes on, if that fails I'll go back to the garage with your other suggestions.  Thanks again.